# cannot get basic bootstrap x-editable to work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I'm trying to use bootstrap x-editable as in the code below. I get the two elements initially displayed allright but when I click at either of them I get a popup saying:

```
<div class="editable-loading"></div>
```

Additionally, the following error is logged to the console:

```
[12:38:17.817] NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 
(NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMHTMLInputElement.setSelectionRange] @  http://localhost/test/bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js:854
```

What am I missing?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css"/>
<script src="bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[data-role="editable"]').editable();
});
</script>


<a data-type="select" title="Select" data-role="editable" data-source="['one', 'two', 'three']"
   data-placement="right" id="myid">Select test</a>
<a data-role="editable" title="Input" id="myid2" data-placement="right">Input test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it may be related to version incompatibilities across jquery/bootstrap/editable. Found out that the following combination of resources works fine:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/assets/x-editable/bootstrap-editable/css/bootstrap- editable.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/assets/x-editable/bootstrap-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>
```